# Type mismatch, found Unit, required Int. Using pattern matching, Scala with Java libraries

Tags: java, scala

I'm trying to register some udfs (user defined functions) for spark sql and when I try to compile I get a type mismatch error for the following code:

```
csc.udf.register("DATEADD", (datePart: String, number: Int, date: Timestamp) => {
    val time: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance
    datePart match {
        case "Y" => time.add(Calendar.YEAR, number)
        case "M" => time.add(Calendar.MONTH, number)
        case "D" => time.add(Calendar.DATE, number)
        case "h" => time.add(Calendar.HOUR, number)
        case "m" => time.add(Calendar.MINUTE, number)
        case "s" => time.add(Calendar.SECOND, number)
        case _ => 0
    }
}: Int)
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
[error] /vagrant/SQLJob/src/main/scala/sqljob/context/CassandraSQLContextFactory.scala:111: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: Int
[error]                                 case "Y" => time.add(Calendar.YEAR: Int, number)
[error]                                                     ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed Jul 2, 2015 4:19:29 PM
```

The Calendar class is from java.util.Calendar

Timestamp if from java.sql.Timestamp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of your function is `(String, Int, Timestamp) => Int` so it should return an `Int`.

`Calendar.add` is the last expression and therefore returned by the function, but its return type is `Unit` instead of `Int`. That's why you get an error telling you that.

Answer (score 1):

`Calendar.add` actually mutates the object and returns `void` (`Unit`in Scala). You should instead call one of the accessor methods on `time` to retrieve a numerical representation of it.